# Click listener in flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

How can I add click listener in `Flatlist`?

My code:

```js
renderItem({item, index}){
    return <View style = {{
    flex:1,
    margin: 5, 
    minWidth: 170, 
    maxWidth: 223,
    height: 304,
    maxHeight: 304,
    backgroundColor: '#ccc',
    }}/>
}
render(){
return(<FlatList
contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'},{key:'c'}]}
renderItem={this.renderItem}
/>);
}
}
```

Update 1: I used button but it is not working in `Flatlist`. However using only button instead of `Flatlist`, it works. Why is it not working in `Flatlist` renderItem?

```js
_listener = () => {
    alert("clicked");
}

renderItem({item, index}){
    return<View>
      <Button
          title = "Button"
          color = "#ccc"
          onPress={this._listener}
      />
    </View>
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to wrap your row element (inside your renderItem method) inside `<TouchableWithoutFeedback>` tag. `TouchableWithoutFeedback` takes onPress as it's prop where you can provide onPress event.

For `TouchableWithoutFeedback` refer this [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html)

Comment: Hi, I've used button inside renderItem in flatlist but the click listener is not working. Please hav a look at the update in above question. I've used TouchableWithoutFeedback as well but with no luck.

Comment: @AmritaStha replace onPress={this._listener} with onPress={this._listener()}

Comment: thanks a lot it helped. Actually binding the function worked.

Answer (score 27):

I used `TouchableWithoutFeedback`. For that, you need to add all the renderItem elements (i.e your row) into the `TouchableWithoutFeedback`. Then add the `onPress` event and pass the FaltList item to the onPress event.

```
import {View, FlatList, Text, TouchableWithoutFeedback} from 'react-native';

render() {

  return (

      <FlatList style={styles.list}

          data={this.state.data}

          renderItem={({item}) => (

              <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={ () => this.actionOnRow(item)}>

                  <View>
                     <Text>ID: {item.id}</Text>
                     <Text>Title: {item.title}</Text>
                  </View>

             </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

         )}
      /> 
   );
}

actionOnRow(item) {
   console.log('Selected Item :',item);
}
```

Comment: i want to update particular item value , so is it possible with this logic ?

Comment: @Anuj Yes its possible. On tap item, get that item, update that particular item value, then update your array and reload the list.

Comment: Thanks i did it ,

Comment: @Manish Hi Manish, I am using the same code. But actionOnRow(item) getting called when I click twice on the FlatList item. Can you tell me what mistake I did?

Comment: @BoominadhaPrakashM Can you share code? Because its may be issue in UI components.

Comment: @Manish I fixed that issue. Problem is I have added FlatList inside the scrollview. So, the ScrollView didn't allow the tap on the FlatList. So, I have added keyboardShouldPersistTaps to 'handled' to ScrollView. Then it started working. Thanks :)

Comment: @BoominadhaPrakashM Good :)

Answer (score 13):

I used `TouchableOpacity`. and it's working great.This will give you click feedback. which will not be provided by `TouchableWithoutFeedback`. I did the following:

```
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
```

.
.
.

```
_onPress = () => {
     // your code on item press
  };

render() {
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPress}>
      <View>
        <Text>List item text</Text>
      </View>
   </TouchableOpacity>
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are facing flatlist row first click issue
please add below property to flatlist.

disableScrollViewPanResponder = {true}

Answer (score 3):

The `Pressable` component is now preferred over `TouchableWithoutFeedback` (and `TouchableOpacity`). According to the React Native docs for `TouchableWithoutFeedback`:

> If you're looking for a more extensive and future-proof way to handle touch-based input, check out the Pressable API.

Example implementation:

```js
import { Pressable } from "react-native";

render() {
  return(
    <FlatList
      contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
      data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}, {key:'c'}]}
      renderItem={({item}) => (
        <Pressable onPress={this._listener}>
          // BUILD VIEW HERE, e.g. this.renderItem(item)
        </Pressable>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

References

1. `TouchableWithoutFeedback` (React Native): https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback
2. `Pressable` (React Native): https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to add Touchable related component into your Flatlist renderItem. Just pass `onTouchStart` prop to your Flatlist.

in example:

```
<FlatList
  style={themedStyles.flatListContainer}
  data={translations}
  renderItem={renderItem}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${item.originalText}____${index}`}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  ListEmptyComponent={renderEmptyListComponent}
  onTouchStart={onBackgroundPressed}
/>
```